# isometry group of double torus

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry

Consider the double-torus, i.e., the orientable genus-$2$ surface. By embedding it into $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can get an induced metric from the usual Euclidean metric.

What's the isometry group of this double-torus? How does one think of it?

Answer (score 2):

Generically, the isometry group will be trivial.

In any case, the isometry group will be finite (unlike the genus zero or one case where a surface of revolution is possible).  See, for example, the book *Finite groups of mapping classes of surfaces* by Zieschang.

The fact that your surface is embedded in three-space should give a further non-trivial restriction on the allowable isometry groups.  Points realising the diameter will be permuted by any isometry.  This should prevent the surface from turning "inside out".